# Generating a call tree or abstract syntax tree in a mixed source code?

Tags: c++, c, fortran

I am looking for a tool to generate a call tree or abstract syntax tree from a mixed-source code, consisting primarily of FORTRAN (some 77, mostly 90) and C++ (with a smattering of plain-old C). Ideally it should be free/open source. On the commercially available end, I have seen [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/index.php), are there others?

**Edit** I am using the Intel Fortran and C++ Compilers.

**Also edit** I'm running Linux. I've also used the Intel VTune utility, but that only gives the call graph for a particular instance (e.g. one branch of an `if`/`then` switch), not the complete structure.

Comment: Many compilers have the option to generate call graphs and the like.  Which compiler are you using, and have your read the manual ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I've updated my question with the compilers I'm using. I've been working my way *slowly* through the documentation. Is this really a RTFM question where I just haven't gotten far enough?

Comment: In the case of the Intel compilers you should leap ahead to where the manual covers call graphs.  It's probably not everything you'd want, but it's something you ought to be familiar with anyway.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That's the problem -- there isn't an obvious "call graph" section in the manual.

Comment: In my copy of the Intel Fortran manual call graphs are covered in chapter 31 along with the code coverage tool.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, is this the right URL? https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-pgo-tools-overview . I do not see anything about call graphs there.

Comment: I posted that link 7.5 years ago, it's no surprise it's no longer useful.

Answer (score 1):

[ROSE](http://rosecompiler.org) might get you what you want reasonably quickly.

Comment: If you somehow happen to actually compile it. (Several tries and very long time on 16 cpu cores in my case.)

Comment: @VladimirF Yeah, I'm having similar issues. And their documentation is a huge mess.

Comment: Mail their list if you're still having trouble. They're generally pretty responsive.